# Validacion de datos javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Buenas necesito de su ayuda para solucionar un codigo, tengo validar que los datos dentro de un objeto exista que me devuelva 1 sino 0, si hay evento que responda con 1 sino 0, si hay evento hay motivo que devuelva el motivo que se encuentra dentro del xml
Si pueden ayudarme soy nuevo en esto, me dieron como tarea.
Si hay algo que mejorar o si hay otra manera de hacer estaria perfecto para que no sea cosigo spagueti

```
const express = require('express');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const setApi = require('./index').default;
const PKCS12 = require('./PKCS12');

const app = express();

app.get('/consulta', (req, res) => {
  const parametros = req.query; // Recibe los parámetros desde la URL

  setApi.consulta(parametros.parametro1, parametros.parametro2, parametros.parametro3, parametros.parametro4, parametros.parametro5)
    .then(xml => {
      const result = xml['ns2:rEnviConsDeResponse'];

      if (result && result['ns2:dCodRes'] === '0422') {
        const xContenDEValue = result['ns2:dMsgRes'];
        const splitData = xContenDEValue.split('<xEvento>');

        if (splitData.length >= 2) {
          const parser = new xml2js.Parser({
            explicitArray: false,
            trim: true,
            cdata: true,
          });

          parser.parseString(splitData[1], (err, parsedResult) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al analizar el XML' });
            } else {
              const motivo = parsedResult?.rGesEve?.rEve?.gGroupTiEvt?.rGeVeCan?.mOtEve || '';
              const Existe = '1';
              const Cancelado = motivo ? '1' : '0';

              const response = {
                'Existe': Existe,
                'Cancelado': Cancelado,
                'Motivo': motivo
              };

              res.json(response);
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        const Existe = '0';
        const Cancelado = '0';
        const Motivo = '';

        const response = {
          'Existe': Existe,
          'Cancelado': Cancelado,
          'Motivo': Motivo
        };

        res.json(response);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor iniciado en el puerto 3000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: pd: al hacer la consulta con un numero que si existe me retorna esto
{
    "Existe": "0",
    "Cancelado": "0",
    "Motivo": ""
}